# How to use string::find with integer? C++

Tags: c++, string, insert

Alright so Im currently writing a little console program and ran into a little problem: Im building a program where one user can think of a word and its being translated into underscores (Word = ____) and another user has to guess the letters (User guesses W; Program erases first _ and inserts W  "W___" till the full word comes out) So right now my code looks something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string wort;
    cout << "Bitte gebe ein Wort ein: ";
    cin >> wort;
    string gesucht = "";
    if (wort.length() == 0 || wort.length() > 63) {
        cout << "Bitte gebe ein gueltiges Wort ein.\n";
    }
    else {
        for (unsigned int a = 1; a <= wort.length(); a++) {
            gesucht.insert(0,  "_");
        }
    }
    cout << "Folgendes Wort wird gesucht:  " << gesucht << endl;
    int versuche = 11;
    char eingabe;
    cin >> eingabe;
    if (wort.find(eingabe) == string::npos) {
        versuche--;
        cout << "Folgendes Wort wird gesucht: " << gesucht << ", du hast noch " << versuche << " Fehlversuche.\n";
    }
    else {
        gesucht.erase(wort.find(eingabe));
        gesucht.insert(wort.find(eingabe), eingabe);
        cout << gesucht << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Problem being this Part:

```
else {
    gesucht.erase(wort.find(eingabe));
    gesucht.insert(wort.find(eingabe), eingabe);
    cout << gesucht << endl;
}
```

It wont let me use `wort.find(eingabe)` as a *Where* so perhaps im trying to convert it into an integer but I dont know how

PS: the code is in german so easier to understand for germans

Comment: Use `to_string(eingable)`. Sorry if it not in code format on my phone

Comment: I wouldn't erase like you're doing.  Keep the real word in a string and keep a string of all underscores. When a letter is guessed, index through the secret string and if the letter matches change the underscore in that position to the letter.  When those two strings match the word has been guessed.  https://ideone.com/D3Uu39

Comment: `find` already returns an integer.

Comment: have you tried `gesucht.erase(wort.find(eingabe), 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that causing problem should look like this:

```
else {
        size_t pos = wort.find(eingabe);
        gesucht.erase(pos, 1);
        gesucht.insert(pos, 1, eingabe);
        cout << gesucht << endl;
    }
```

Because you are dealing with a single char rather than string, you should use correct overload of `.erase` and `.insert`

Comment: Thanks, helped me figure out the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys so I solved my problem, I just added a 1 so it knows how many characters is should add because eingabe is a char.
This is how the working code looks:

```
else {
    gesucht.erase(wort.find(eingabe), 1);
    gesucht.insert(wort.find(eingabe), 1, eingabe);
    cout << gesucht << endl;
}
```